# MySql Select Id <= Maximum value in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

When using the `<=` in a MySql statement, is it possible to make MySql select the maximum value in a table without supplying a value to `<=` in the sql statement?

Eg:

```
id
----
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Eg:

```
// start from the last record when no value is supplied
select id from table where id <= * ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
Result
6
5
4
3
2

// start from the 5th record when a value is supplied
select id from table where id <= 5 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
Result 
5
4
3
2
1
```

My problem is, this statement is in a php function, so I cannot change it dynamically. Is it somehow possible to do what I'm trying, or perhaps another way to get around this?

Comment: What does `<=` have to do with getting the maximum value?  One would normally just use the `max()` function.

Comment: If you want to ignore the top row and you're ordering desc just use an offset of 1.

Comment: I'm trying to get the max value, I'm trying to select 5 records starting from the max, but cannot use max here

Comment: Your question sound like a riddle. What does this means: `5 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5` ? What is the intention ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NULL` instead of using `*`

```
SET @var_search_value = NULL -- OR 5

SELECT id 
FROM   table 
WHERE  id <= @var_search_value OR @var_search_value IS NULL 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Is it possible to just do select * from table where id <= NULL, instead of doing it the way you have? I tried, but it does not work. id is a INT type column in my table.

Comment: No that won't work as `NULL` compared with anything results in `NULL` or `false` value so this query won't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get every record which is less than or equal to the maximum value in a particular column, then logically you want to get every record:

```
select id from table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

No `WHERE` clause is required.

Comment: But I cannot leave out the `<=` in the statement, since it's needed there when a value is supplied. Eg: `<=5` as in my example.

Comment: @Norman: Then when you have a value to use in a `WHERE` clause, add the entire clause.  When you don't have such a value, don't add that clause.  There's no rule that says you can't change your SQL query based on some condition in the code.

Comment: That doesn't work when the OP doesn't want the max value in the table as per example 2..

Comment: @StevieG: Apparently "example 2" changed after my answer was posted...  Still, that's what `if` conditions are for.  The OP can change the query based on a condition in the code.  If there's a value, use a query with a `WHERE` clause.  If there isn't a value, use one without.